# Gunicorn HTTPs certificate and keys

Tags: python, django, ssl, gunicorn

To use ssl with django I use the following command:

```
python3 manage.py runsslserver xx.8x.x3.x4:443 --certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/callservps.online/fullchain.pem --key /etc/letsencrypt/live/callserv.com/privkey.pem
```

To run gunicorn with that certificate and key:

```
gunicorn --bind xx.8x.x3.x4:443:443 -certfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/callserv.online/fullchain.pem -keyfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/callserv.online/privkey.pem callservps.wsgi
```

But, it give me error.

> Can't connect to (xx.8x.x3.x4:443:443)

I think the problem is that the certificate and the key have a .pem extension. But I'm not sure how to implement this correctly to run gunicorn with https and those certificates and keys

Answer (score 2):

generate a key pair and a self-signed public-key certificate with the following `openssl` command. this example generates an elliptic-curve key pair and a self signed public-key certificate, valid for 10 years.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey ec:<(openssl ecparam -name prime256v1) -keyout private_key.pem -out certificate.pem
```

This will prompt you to fill some details.
With both the key and cert files in your project folder, run

```
gunicorn your-project.wsgi --keyfile private_key.pem --certfile certificate.pem
```

Most probably your browser will deny first access as a security risk (because no way of verifying the self-signed certificate, but accept the risk and continue to site).